# Azure AD B2C with WebApi2- calling GraphAPI after authentication

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-ad-b2c

I have a WebApi2 app which servers as api for my app frontend. Now i want to use AD B2C to manage my users - let's say I want to differentiate them by their roles (admin or customer) and for that i created two b2c users groups accordingly. When user logs in i want to display different things for users with different roles (groups).

I'm using [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-api-dotnet) to setup `Startup.Auth.cs` in my WebApi2 project:

```
var tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudience = clientId,
    AuthenticationType = signUpSignInPolicy,
};

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, defaultPolicy))),
});
```

From what I have read b2c doesn't return user's grups in claims for now. Some people suggested I need to call GraphApi after obtaining token to fetch these groups and add them to user's claims:

```
private static async Task<string> GetGroups(string token, string userId)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/memberOf?$select=displayName";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

This is where I've stuck. How can I inject my code to get token for calling graph? I've messed with `OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.Provider`:

```
Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    OnValidateIdentity = (context) =>
    {
        // var token = ??
        // var userId = <get from context's claims>
        // var groups = GetGroups(token, userId);
        // <add to claims>

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
},
```

...but I don't know how to get to token. Maybe that's wrong from the start and I need another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Customer's token cannot be used to call AADGraph/MSGraph Apis. To get token to call graph apis in an automated way, we need app-only access. We need to configre an app in the tenant, the crendetial of which are used to get a token. That token can then be used to call memberOF Api (or any other api which does or require user information to be there)

Here is the sample and explaination of how to call AAD Graph apis in a B2C dependent service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet